# SVG: <animateMotion> & keySplines not working on FF

Tags: animation, firefox, svg

In this example : https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/curved.html the baskets are following the wheel... except on Firefox.

It seems like FF does have a problem with keySplines as attribute to animateMotion.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>Let's go Schueberfouer</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:200,400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-top: 2em;
        }

        .nacelle {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .nointeraction {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        #container {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 600px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        #info {
            font: 200 2em "Fira Sans";
            text-align: center;
        }

        #info button, #module button {
            border: none;
            background-color: #004499;
            color: white;
            padding: 0.6em 1em;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }

        #module {
            position: fixed;
            top: -180vh;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: orange;
            transition: top 2s 1s cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.1, 1);
            left: 0;
            box-shadow: 0px 70px 100px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            padding: 2em;
            overflow: auto;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #module.down {
            top: 0;
        }

        #module h1 {
            font: 200 2em "Fira Sans";
            color: white;
        }
    </style>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="100%" height="100%"  viewBox="0 0 600 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">

        <path d="M30,250a250,250 0 1,0 500,0a250,250 0 1,0 -500,0" id="wire1" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M63.49,375C132.53,494.57,285.43,535.54,405,466.51S565.54,244.57,496.51,125 S274.57-35.54,155,33.49S-5.54,255.43,63.49,375" id="wire2" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M155,466.51c119.57,69.04,272.47,28.07,341.51-91.51S524.57,102.53,405,33.49S132.53,5.43,63.49,125 S35.43,397.47,155,466.51" id="wire3" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M280,500c138.07,0,250-111.93,250-250C530,111.93,418.07,0,280,0S30,111.93,30,250 C30,388.07,141.93,500,280,500" id="wire4" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M405,466.51C524.57,397.47,565.54,244.57,496.51,125S274.57-35.54,155,33.49S-5.54,255.43,63.49,375 S285.43,535.54,405,466.51" id="wire5" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M496.51,375C565.54,255.43,524.57,102.53,405,33.49S132.53,5.43,63.49,125S35.43,397.47,155,466.51 S427.47,494.57,496.51,375" id="wire6" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M530,250C530,111.93,418.07,0,280,0S30,111.93,30,250c0,138.07,111.93,250,250,250 S530,388.07,530,250" id="wire7" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M496.51,125C427.47,5.43,274.57-35.54,155,33.49S-5.54,255.43,63.49,375S285.43,535.54,405,466.51 S565.54,244.57,496.51,125" id="wire8" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M405,33.49C285.43-35.54,132.53,5.43,63.49,125S35.43,397.47,155,466.51S427.47,494.57,496.51,375 S524.57,102.53,405,33.49" id="wire9" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M280,0C141.93,0,30,111.93,30,250s111.93,250,250,250s250-111.93,250-250S418.07,0,280,0" id="wire10" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M155,33.49C35.43,102.53-5.54,255.43,63.49,375S285.43,535.54,405,466.51S565.54,244.57,496.51,125 S274.57-35.54,155,33.49" id="wire11" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M63.49,125C-5.54,244.57,35.43,397.47,155,466.51S427.47,494.57,496.51,375S524.57,102.53,405,33.49 S132.53,5.43,63.49,125" id="wire12" fill="transparent" />

        <image xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/roue.png" x="50" y="10" height="500" width="500">
            <animateTransform attributeName = "transform"
                            attributeType = "XML"
                            type          = "rotate"
                            from          = "360 300 260"
                            to            = "0 300 260" 
                            calcMode      = "spline"
                            keySplines    = "0 0.55 0.45 1"
                            keyTimes      = "0;1"        
                            restart       = "always" 
                            dur           = "10s"
                            repeatCount   = "1"/>
        </image>


        <image class="nacelle" id="n1"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire1"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n2"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire2"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n3"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire3"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n4"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire4"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n5"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire5"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n6"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire6"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n7"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire7"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n8"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire8"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n9"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire9"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n10"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire10"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n11"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire11"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n12"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire12"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nointeraction" xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nmat.png" x="150" y="240" width="300" />

    </svg>
</div>
<div id="info">
    <p>Choisissez votre nacelle</p>
</div>
<div id="module">
    <h1 id="module_title">Bienvenue dans la nacelle</h1>
    <button onClick="hidemodule()">Refermer</button>
</div>
<script>
var nacelle = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('svg .nacelle'));

nacelle.forEach(function(el) {
   el.addEventListener("click", function () {
       document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "<p>Vous avez sélectionné la nacelle " + el.id.substr(1) + "</p><button onClick='anewride(" + el.id.substr(1) + ")'>C'est parti !</button>";
   });
});

function anewride (num) {
    document.querySelectorAll("svg animateMotion").forEach(element => {
            element.beginElement();
        });
        document.querySelectorAll("svg animateTransform").forEach(element => {
            element.beginElement();
        }); 
    document.getElementById("module_title").innerHTML = "Bienvenue dans la nacelle " + num;
    document.getElementById("module").classList.add("down");
}

function hidemodule () {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Choisissez votre nacelle";
    document.getElementById("module").classList.remove("down");
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I replace this attribute with keyPoints (https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/v1.html), it works. But... for synchronicity reasons, I would like to rely on keySplines.

Would you have a hint? Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: ‘keySplines’ values are the control points. Thus, there must be one fewer sets of control points than there are ‘keyTimes’.  https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html Also The attribute value is a semicolon-separated list of control point descriptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to set the `keyPoints` attribute to `"0;1"` in addition to setting the times and the spline. `from`/`to` values (or their defaults) cannot apply. The Chrome behavior, as far as I can see, has no ground in the [spec](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#AnimateMotionElement).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>Let's go Schueberfouer</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:200,400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-top: 2em;
        }

        .nacelle {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .nointeraction {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        #container {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 600px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        #info {
            font: 200 2em "Fira Sans";
            text-align: center;
        }

        #info button, #module button {
            border: none;
            background-color: #004499;
            color: white;
            padding: 0.6em 1em;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }

        #module {
            position: fixed;
            top: -180vh;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: orange;
            transition: top 2s 1s cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.1, 1);
            left: 0;
            box-shadow: 0px 70px 100px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            padding: 2em;
            overflow: auto;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #module.down {
            top: 0;
        }

        #module h1 {
            font: 200 2em "Fira Sans";
            color: white;
        }
    </style>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="100%" height="100%"  viewBox="0 0 600 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">

        <path d="M30,250a250,250 0 1,0 500,0a250,250 0 1,0 -500,0" id="wire1" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M63.49,375C132.53,494.57,285.43,535.54,405,466.51S565.54,244.57,496.51,125 S274.57-35.54,155,33.49S-5.54,255.43,63.49,375" id="wire2" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M155,466.51c119.57,69.04,272.47,28.07,341.51-91.51S524.57,102.53,405,33.49S132.53,5.43,63.49,125 S35.43,397.47,155,466.51" id="wire3" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M280,500c138.07,0,250-111.93,250-250C530,111.93,418.07,0,280,0S30,111.93,30,250 C30,388.07,141.93,500,280,500" id="wire4" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M405,466.51C524.57,397.47,565.54,244.57,496.51,125S274.57-35.54,155,33.49S-5.54,255.43,63.49,375 S285.43,535.54,405,466.51" id="wire5" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M496.51,375C565.54,255.43,524.57,102.53,405,33.49S132.53,5.43,63.49,125S35.43,397.47,155,466.51 S427.47,494.57,496.51,375" id="wire6" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M530,250C530,111.93,418.07,0,280,0S30,111.93,30,250c0,138.07,111.93,250,250,250 S530,388.07,530,250" id="wire7" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M496.51,125C427.47,5.43,274.57-35.54,155,33.49S-5.54,255.43,63.49,375S285.43,535.54,405,466.51 S565.54,244.57,496.51,125" id="wire8" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M405,33.49C285.43-35.54,132.53,5.43,63.49,125S35.43,397.47,155,466.51S427.47,494.57,496.51,375 S524.57,102.53,405,33.49" id="wire9" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M280,0C141.93,0,30,111.93,30,250s111.93,250,250,250s250-111.93,250-250S418.07,0,280,0" id="wire10" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M155,33.49C35.43,102.53-5.54,255.43,63.49,375S285.43,535.54,405,466.51S565.54,244.57,496.51,125 S274.57-35.54,155,33.49" id="wire11" fill="transparent" />

        <path d="M63.49,125C-5.54,244.57,35.43,397.47,155,466.51S427.47,494.57,496.51,375S524.57,102.53,405,33.49 S132.53,5.43,63.49,125" id="wire12" fill="transparent" />

        <image xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/roue.png" x="50" y="10" height="500" width="500">
            <animateTransform attributeName = "transform"
                            attributeType = "XML"
                            type          = "rotate"
                            from          = "360 300 260"
                            to            = "0 300 260" 
                            calcMode      = "spline"
                            keySplines    = "0 0.55 0.45 1"
                            keyTimes      = "0;1"        
                            restart       = "always" 
                            dur           = "10s"
                            repeatCount   = "1"/>
        </image>


        <image class="nacelle" id="n1"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire1"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n2"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire2"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n3"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire3"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n4"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire4"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n5"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire5"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n6"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire6"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n7"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire7"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n8"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire8"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n9"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire9"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n10"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire10"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n11"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire11"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nacelle" id="n12"  xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nacelle.png" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50">
            <animateMotion  restart="always" dur="10s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;1" keySplines="0 0.55 0.45 1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline">
                <mpath xlink:href="#wire12"></mpath>
            </animateMotion>
        </image>

        <image class="nointeraction" xlink:href="https://data.wort.lu/tests/css/nmat.png" x="150" y="240" width="300" />

    </svg>
</div>
<div id="info">
    <p>Choisissez votre nacelle</p>
</div>
<div id="module">
    <h1 id="module_title">Bienvenue dans la nacelle</h1>
    <button onClick="hidemodule()">Refermer</button>
</div>
<script>
var nacelle = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('svg .nacelle'));

nacelle.forEach(function(el) {
   el.addEventListener("click", function () {
       document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "<p>Vous avez sélectionné la nacelle " + el.id.substr(1) + "</p><button onClick='anewride(" + el.id.substr(1) + ")'>C'est parti !</button>";
   });
});

function anewride (num) {
    document.querySelectorAll("svg animateMotion").forEach(element => {
            element.beginElement();
        });
        document.querySelectorAll("svg animateTransform").forEach(element => {
            element.beginElement();
        }); 
    document.getElementById("module_title").innerHTML = "Bienvenue dans la nacelle " + num;
    document.getElementById("module").classList.add("down");
}

function hidemodule () {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Choisissez votre nacelle";
    document.getElementById("module").classList.remove("down");
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate.